# JHipster JDL Parse Error with Fractions Values in field min

Tags: java, jhipster, jdl

I am developing JDL file to generate my entites in JHipster. I have this entity:

```
entity Currency {
    name String required,
    conversionRate Double required min(0.0001) 
}
```

I got this error:

Executing jhipster:import-jdl entities.jdl

Options: 
The jdl is being parsed.
An error has occurred:
        SyntaxError
Error message:
        Expected ")", ['\n'|'\t'|'\r'|' '| | ], or [0-9] but "." found.

Position:
        At l.9.

Error: SyntaxError: Expected ")", ['\n'|'\t'|'\r'|' '| | ], or [0-9] but "." found.
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: ERROR! 
Error while parsing entities from JDL

```
at Environment.error (/Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:157:40)
at error (/Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/generator-base.js:1964:18)
at parseJDL (/Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/generator-jhipster/generators/import-jdl/index.js:113:26)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:399:25)
at /Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/run-async/index.js:25:25
at /Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:19
at self.env.runLoop.add.completed (/Users/Macpro/Projects/pf-jhipster4/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/index.js:400:11)
at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
```

I tried escaping the . with no success. Seems that, fraction is not accepted in  double min value.

Note that, using integers Works with no problem, as example:

```
conversionRate Double required min(1)
```

Comment: The same problem is still there with JHipster 5.50 - no fractions in min() values for Floats.

Comment: It should be easy to fix it on Jhipster codebase.